# Conformal mapping on two paths

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

GIven $ f (z) = z^2$ .

Let $p  = (0, −1)$ and take the curves $γ_1, γ_2$ passing through $p$ as $γ_1 = $arc of the unit circle through $(0, −1) $ counterclockwise and $γ_2 $ = a straight line through $p$  with slope $m = \sqrt{3}$ .

Check that f preserves the oriented angle between $γ_1, γ_2$ by first identifying
the images of these curves under $f$.

Comment: What is the exact scheme i need to follow t solve this question ? Pls help

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The image of the unit circle under the squaring map is still the unit circle,the arc will now be different.Think about $e^{i \theta}  -> e^ {2i \theta} $ while $r=1$ is invariant. In the drawing the blue segment maps onto the red segment.

A line, through the point (0,-1) will be a Parabola.

So,  let $ t = u $ , $m(t+1) = v $  be a line through (0,-1) with slope m: then we are looking at:
($u^2 - v^2 $, $2uv$) in the w plane. Which becomes: ( $t^2 - m^2(t+1)^2 $, $2t*m(t+1)$ ), if you work with this parametric equation you will find it is a parabola , possibly rotated , in the w plane. If $ m = \sqrt 3 $ , the cyan line is mapped onto the blue parabola. Since (0,1) is mapped onto (1,0) the intersection of the arc segment(blue) and line segment(cyan) is mapped onto the arc segment(red) and parabolic segment(purple). (It remains to show the angles of the segments are equal , we know this to be true since the map is conformal.)

Comment: What is the image of cirlce under squaring map ( Basically whats the image of function $g$ under another function $f$ ? ) is it just $f(g(p))$ ?

Comment: No, it isn't composition, z --> z^2  really means double the angle on the unit cicle, but notice how it jumps around, i --> -1 .